# Is there any way in which we can stub meteor functions using cypress for unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js, cypress

I am trying to stub meteor methods and API Cypress unit testing.
My api services are deployed on spring container. [produces and consumes JSON]

Tried using the below code for API stubbing:

```
cy.server()
cy.fixture('samplejson.json').as('sample')
cy.route('POST','https://myURL/host/login', '@sample')
```

This doesn't intercept the API call as its not a XHR request (using REST APIs).

Also, since the meteor framework uses a definite template for its template.js file, not sure how to stub the methods with `cy.stub()`.

If anyone is able to successfully stub Meteor calls such as `Meteor.call()`(in client side) or `HTTP.call()`(in methods.js), please share any references or examples.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with meteor. It does not show as a XHR request in your browser? Does it show in cypress as a API call (I mean in the runner output on the left when you run the test)?

Comment: @Maccurt Yes, it shows in the cypress runner pane (Method, URL,Stubbed) but the count hit is null. I tries the using XHR  request in client side (just to check), it worked then. The problem is, according to my project setup, I cannot use XHR request for any API call.

Comment: @Lalit Did you ever figure this out? If so I'd love a pointer! Thanks.